# FactoryPattern without If-else construct

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns

Someone asked me if I can create factory pattern in java without using If-else construct. So I come with the following. Please provide your inputs if this seems a good example for using factories.

```
public enum EnumButtonFactory {

RADIO(RadioButton.class),
SUBMIT(SubmitButton.class),
NORMAL(NormalButton.class);

private Class<? extends Button> button;

EnumButtonFactory(Class<? extends Button> b) {
    this.button = b;
}

public Button get() {
    try {
        return button.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
 }
}
```

and the usage is dead simple

```
    Button button = null;   
    button = EnumButtonFactory.RADIO.get();
    button.click();
```

Comment: Try codereview instead...